# Как сделать автоматический рестарт mariadb-10.3 в контейнере Docker при падении?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, docker, mariadb

Есть БД установленная в контейнере докер, бывает она падает, как можно отслеживать это дело и рестартить ее автоматически? Система Centos панель управления ispmanager/

Answer (score 1):

У докера есть свои [политики](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/) относительно работы контейнера, но не службы внутри контейнера. Чтобы настроить политику перезапуска для контейнера, используйте флаг --restart при использовании команды docker run.

- **no**   Do not automatically restart the container. (the default)
- **on-failure**   Restart the container if it exits due to an error, which manifests as a non-zero exit code.
- **always**   Always restart the container if it stops. If it is manually stopped, it is restarted only when Docker daemon restarts or
  the container itself is manually restarted. (See the second bullet
  listed in restart policy details)
- **unless-stopped**   Similar to always, except that when the container is stopped (manually or otherwise), it is not restarted even after
  Docker daemon restarts.

А далее используйте средства мониторинга и скрипты. Например, забикс, и в случае сбоя прикрепите триггер(скрипт), который будет запускать ваш контейнер.

Comment: Приветствую! В том то и проблема, что сам контейнер работает, а падает сама служба maria-db-10.3